# Safari does not support input="time", need an alternative for that

Tags: html, jquery, css, time, safari

I have a simple form that has an input tag with type= "time"

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="appt">Select a time:</label>
  <input type="time" id="appt" name="appt">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Unfortunately Safari does not support it and I need an alternative which runs on Safari.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand as Safari seems to support time perfectly OK. Is there more code around that is affecting this?

Comment: I am on Safari version 14.1.1 , and if I go to this link, the time input does not work 

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_time

Comment: Working OK for me on Safari on IOS 14.7.1 What device/operating system are you using, and what do you see? I see a popup which I have to then click to then choose a new time. It gets submitted and returned to the w3schools system OK.

Comment: @GurkeeratSondhi can you explain what do you mean not working? the input doesn't appear? or you can not submit it?

Comment: Nothing happens when I click on the input tag for Select a time : 
Will update my Safari to 14.7.1 and give it a go.

Comment: type="text" is what safari should be defaulting to if it doesn't support type="time". type="text" should work just fine. what you're probably looking for is a plugin to replace default functionality when a browser doesn't implement it, which is very different from something not working.